# Sequence of Measures that converge weakly to a non product measure

Tags: probability, weak-convergence

Can someone provide an example of a sequence of probability measures $\{u_n\}$ which converges to a measure $u$ that is not a probability measure?

Comment: "Product" as in title, or "probability" as in the body?  What kind of space are you talking about, anyway?  If the underlying measurable space is finite, the answer is "no".  And, for good measure, precisely what do you mean by "converge" or "converge weakly"?

Comment: Meant probability measure in borel space. I am trying to understand why the definitinion of tight measures is needed when we have a sequence of probability measures coverging to a measure that may not be a prob measure. Specifically, why the definition is necessary if we start with borel prob measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much revised.

If by weak convergence of the sequence of probability measures $\mu_n$ to the measure $\mu$ you mean that for each continuous bounded $f$ the limit $\lim_n\langle \mu_n,f\rangle = \langle \mu,f\rangle$ holds, you can indeed conclude that $\mu$ is a probability measure.  Because the constant function $1$ is continuous and bounded.  So the answer to your question is *no*.

The condition of tightness brought up in your comment is meant to rule out convergences like the following.  If the underlying space $X$ is not compact,  such as $\mathbb R$, the sequence of point masses $\mu_n$ concentrating their mass at $\{n\}$ is so-called *vaguely convergent* to the zero measure $\mu$:  the convergence $\langle \mu_n,f\rangle\to\langle\mu,f\rangle$ is verified for all continuous  $f$ of compact support.  But these $\mu_n$ do not converge weakly to a measure.

Comment: My apologies, I was under the impression that there was a universal definition of weak convergence. The definition I have been using is the following: $\int f du_n\rightarrow \int fdu$ for all continuous bounded functions $f$.

Comment: That makes sense now. So if we have weak convergence as I defined above then we are guaranteed that the sequence converges to a p.m. by definition. We need tightness to ensure  that if a sequence of  p.m converges to  some measure it is a p.m. For example the theorem that states if $\{u_n\}$ are a tight sequence of p.m then there exists a subsequence $\{u_{n_k}\}$ that converges to $u$ a p.m. Thank you.